# flutter how to check if Map is null?

Tags: android, flutter

map defined as follow:

```
Map<String,dynamic> allAvailableTime;
```

the map should be empty when user initialize the page:

I would like to perform null check before getting data from the map however these are not working...

check 1:

```
allAvailableTime == null ?
```

error:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
```

check 2:

```
allAvailableTime == {} ?
```

the check should return `True`, but it returns `False` instead ..

check 3:

```
allAvailableTime.isEmpty ?
```

error 3:

```
The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isEmpty
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To null Check. It should be nullable

```dart
void main() {
 
 //1. Making Map Nullable 
 Map<String,dynamic>? allAvailableTime;
 print(allAvailableTime==null);
 //Output: true
  
  
 //2. If you dont want to make it nullable
 Map<String,dynamic> allAvailableTime1 = {};
 print(allAvailableTime1.isEmpty);
  //Output: true
}
```

Without NullSafety

```dart
void main() {
 
 //1. Making Map Nullable 
 Map<String,dynamic> allAvailableTime;
 print(allAvailableTime==null);
 //Output: true
  
  
 //2. If you dont want to make it nullable
 Map<String,dynamic> allAvailableTime1 = {};
 print(allAvailableTime1.isEmpty);
  //Output: true
}
```

Comment: thanks, very useful

Answer (score 2):

If you want a null map, you have to do this.

```dart
Map<String,dynamic>? allAvailableTime;
```

Comment: im not using the null safety version

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```
Map<String, dynamic> allAvailableTime;
 if (allAvailableTime?.isEmpty ?? true) {
  // Returns true if there is no key/value pair in the map.
 }
```